# Bluberries start to turn yellow and then brown

Tags: trees

I water them and the soil's always moist, though not sopping wet so as to avoid root rot, but for some reason, they keep turning yellow then brown.  Slowly my bush is going to be nothing, what do I do, it's my first time growing blueberries.

Comment: We need more information and a photo if possible please. Is the plant in a pot or in the ground? How long have you had it? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: What is the pH of the soil? It seem basic soil (clay?).

Comment: That should not be all one long sentence.

Comment: Blueberries don't like wet roots . Ideal is sandy soil with a high water table ( 5 +/- feet down).